# Generating DEF and .A files using GCC/cmake

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile, cmake, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build Alexa SDK here:
https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk

Followed the guide and was able to build the SDK and sample app but generated libraries are DLLs.

I need to re-build it to output DEFs and .A files.

Looked around the code and saw this on `build.make` (which apparently was generated when I built it the first time):

```
# External object files for target CapabilitiesDelegate
CapabilitiesDelegate_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =

bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: CapabilitiesDelegate/src/CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/CapabilitiesDelegate.cpp.obj
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: CapabilitiesDelegate/src/CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/build.make
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: ACL/src/libACL.dll.a
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: RegistrationManager/src/libRegistrationManager.dll.a
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libcurl.dll.a
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: AVSCommon/libAVSCommon.dll.a
bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll: C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libcurl.dll.a
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX shared library ../../bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll"
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a $(CapabilitiesDelegate_OBJECTS) $(CapabilitiesDelegate_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS)
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -DDEBUG -DACSDK_DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED -Wall -Werror -Wsign-compare -g -Wno-error=class-memaccess -DRAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING  -shared -o ../../bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../ACL/src/libACL.dll.a ../../RegistrationManager/src/libRegistrationManager.dll.a -lcurl ../../AVSCommon/libAVSCommon.dll.a -lcurl -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
CapabilitiesDelegate/src/CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/build: bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll
```

On top of this file, saw this:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MSYS Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.14
```

So..
1. Any thoughts on how this `build.make` is generated? I tried searching on the checkout but can't find any reference. I am hoping I can modify the file that actually generates this `build.make` to create `.a` (static) rather than `.dll.a.`

2. With this:

```
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a $(CapabilitiesDelegate_OBJECTS) $(CapabilitiesDelegate_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS)
    cd /C/Users/Thegeek/Desktop/Alexa/Alexa_32bit/build/CapabilitiesDelegate/src && /C/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -DDEBUG -DACSDK_DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED -Wall -Werror -Wsign-compare -g -Wno-error=class-memaccess -DRAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING  -shared -o ../../bin/libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libCapabilitiesDelegate.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/CapabilitiesDelegate.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../../ACL/src/libACL.dll.a ../../RegistrationManager/src/libRegistrationManager.dll.a -lcurl ../../AVSCommon/libAVSCommon.dll.a -lcurl -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

How can I change it to create a static library instead? There appears to be other libraries dependent on this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: "1. Any thoughts on how this build.make is generated?" - This file is generated with `cmake` runnable. The second comment in the file suggests that "MSYS Makefiles" [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) has been used, this is why resulted files has extensions like `.dll.a`. You may choose other generator, just make sure that you have appropriate build tool and the compiler.

Comment: "How can I change it to create a static library instead?" - It is `CMakeLists.txt` files which are responsible to build libraries. And it seems they **hardcode** creating shared libraries. See e.g. [CapabilityAgents/AIP/src/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/blob/master/CapabilityAgents/AIP/src/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Thanks! CMakeLists.txt solves it! Thank you!